# What's the most efficient way to sum up an ndarray in numpy while minimizing floating point inaccuracy?

Tags: python, numpy, precision

I have a big matrix with values that vary greatly in orders of magnitude. To calculate the sum as accurate as possible, my approach would be to reshape the ndarray into a 1-dimensional array, sort it and then add it up, starting with the smallest entries. Is there a better / more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Not sure about accuracy, but for performance, you can look into `numexpr` module.

Comment: Look [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/298339-more-accurate-sum/)

Comment: Why does numpy.sum(matrix) not do the job for you? How do you measure that this is inaccurate?

Comment: Parseval's identity for the DFT has an error of about 1e-8. Some of that certainly comes from the DFT itself, but I want to minimize the inaccuracies wherever I can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that, given floating point precision problems, the best known algorithm for your task is [Kahan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm).  For practical purposes, Kahan summation has an error bound that is independent of the number of summands, while naive summation has an error bound that grows linearly with the number of summands.

NumPy does not use Kahan summation, and there is no easy way of implementing it without a big performance tradeoff.  But it uses the next best thing, [pairwise summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_summation), where error grows, under some reasonable assumptions, like the square root of the logarithm of the number of summands.

So it is very likely that Numpy is on its own already able to provide sufficiently good precision for your problem.  To validate this, I would actually run a few sample cases through Kahan summation (the pseudocode in the Wikipedia link above can be trivially converted to Python), and take this as the golden, best possible result, and compare it against:

1. Calling `np.sum` on your matrix as is.
2. Calling `np.sum` on your matrix after reshaping to 1D, which may give better results if your matrix is not contiguous in memory.
3. Calling `np.sum` on a sorted version of the 1D array.

For most cases these last three options should behave similarly, but the only way to know is to actually test it.

Comment: The three np.sum variants did indeed deliver the same result, but Kahan summation improved it noticably. Thanks!

Comment: There's a `math.fsum` that's supposed give better accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add a simple improvement you can make to numpy sum: use np.float128 (quadruple precision) as intermediate value, then cast back to standard 64bit float:

```
np.float64(np.sum(array, dtype=np.float128))
```

This casts the values to be summed to quadruple precision, significantly reducing rounding errors. This is slower than numpy.sum with 64 bits, but significantly faster than fsum or sorting the array first.

As an example I was evaluating a 1000x1000 matrix of absolute values from the standard cauchy distribution
`matrix = np.abs(np.random.standard_cauchy([1000, 1000]))`. The 128bit result is identical to fsum, with np.sum after sorting being better than without, but still less precise.

Evaluation time measured with `%timeit`:

```
np.sum(matrix): 370 μs
np.float64(np.sum(matrix, dtype=np.float128)): 4.3 ms
math.fsum(matrix.flatten()): 60 ms
np.sum(np.sort(matrix.flatten())): 78 ms
```

Notes:

1. float128 is not available on Windows afaik.
2. numba does so far not support 128bit floats.